# Agrupar array multidimensional en java

Tags: java

tengo un array como este:

```
"array": [
            {"fecha":"07/07/2020", "datos":1, "nombre":"nombre"},
            {"fecha":"07/07/2020", "datos":2, "nombre":"nombre"},
            {"fecha":"07/07/2020", "datos":3, "nombre":"nombre"},
        ]
```

y quería saber si se puede agrupar por fecha.
que me quede asi:

```
{"fecha":"07/07/2020", "datos":6, "nombre":"nombre"}
```

Edito:

```
List<General> general = new ArrayList<>();
for (Dato dato : dato) {
d.getFecha(dato.getFecha());
d.getNombre(dato.getNombre());
d.getDato(dato.getDato());
}
general.add(d);
```

yoquiero que despues de recorrer el arrary en general quedaria como el de arriba pero yo quiero que al recorrerlo se agrupe por fecha.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Esa notación es JSON. Si recibes esa información en una petición REST lo normal es que el ObjectMapper cree una List, no un array. ¿Estás segura de que tienes un array? Y tal como está escrito no es multidimensional, es un array de objetos que tienen 3 atributos o propiedades

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos tu código de Java??? qué has intentado???

Por otro lado, me parece que estás intentando almacenar distintos tipos de datos en un array, el cual es una estructura que sólo almacena un tipo de datos. Quizás lo mejor sería optar por otro tipo de estructura, como un List.

Comment: edite la pregunta y si es un List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigar un buen rato, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

Entiendo que tienes un **Array** de objetos que almacenas en un **ArrayList** que quieres ordenar por el atributo fecha de cada objeto. Para ello, se podría implementar un par de métodos sobre la clase **Dato**:

**Método ordenarFechas()**:

Será el encargado de comparar las fechas, para ello uso un **Comparator** que a su vez implementa el método **compare()**. ***OJO***, para que lo haga correctamente hay que pasar las fechas **de formato String a formato Fecha**, que es lo que hace el método stringAFecha() que detallo justo debajo de este método.

```
    public static Comparator<Dato> ordenarFechas = new Comparator<Dato>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Dato d1, Dato d2) {
        String StudentName1 = d1.getFecha();
        String StudentName2 = d2.getFecha();

        return stringAFecha(StudentName1).compareTo(stringAFecha(StudentName2));
    }
};
```

**Método stringAFecha()**:

**Transforma un String en la fecha con el formato que le indicamos**, que es lo que necesitamos. Para ello, hago uso de **DateFormat** y **SimpleDateFormat**.

```
   public static Date stringAFecha(String fechaEnString)  {
    DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date fecha = null;
    try {
        fecha = formato.parse(fechaEnString);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dato.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return fecha;
}
```

Los **implementamos sobre el Main** de esta forma:

```
    Collections.sort(miLista, Dato.ordenarFechas);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*****************");
    System.out.println("Lista ordenada por fechas:");
    Iterator it = miLista.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

**Salida**:

```
Lista sin ordenar:
Dato{fecha=01/02/2027, datos=sassa, nombre=Pepe}
Dato{fecha=02/05/2022, datos=adasd, nombre=Paula}
Dato{fecha=03/05/2021, datos=hfg, nombre=Juana}
Dato{fecha=03/05/1999, datos=sdf, nombre=Manolo}

*************************************************
Lista ordenada por fechas:
Dato{fecha=03/05/1999, datos=sdf, nombre=Manolo}
Dato{fecha=03/05/2021, datos=hfg, nombre=Juana}
Dato{fecha=02/05/2022, datos=adasd, nombre=Paula}
Dato{fecha=01/02/2027, datos=sassa, nombre=Pepe}
```

Seguramente se pueda mejorar, pero funciona. He intentado adaptarme a tu código lo máximo posible, pero sin tenerlo completo, es complicado. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.